# KDE Konsole incorrect reboot behaviour

Tags: arch-linux, kde, startup, plasma, konsole

I'm running KDE Plasma on Arch Linux. Upon rebooting my PC, Plasma re-opens the applications that were open prior to reboot. This is desirable behaviour and functions as expected for all applications except Konsole.

Konsole opens as expected, however it always opens two tabs which open in directories that I used while at university and installing the yay package manager. Specifically, the first tab opens to (censored for privacy):
/home/lily/Documents/[uni]/[subject]/Week_4/Prac_code

And the second tab opens to:
/home/lily/Downloads/yay

Why does this happen and how can I solve it? If I close and then re-open Konsole it opens to ~/ as expected. However I would like it to open to the tabs an directories that I most recently used upon reboot.

I've tried modifying my profile however this did not solve the issue. I've used Arch and KDE many times in the past and never had this problem.